# Service mocked with Jest causes "The module factory of jest.mock() is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables" error

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a call to a service but I'm struggeling with the following message: **The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables**.

I'm using babel with ES6 syntax, jest and enzyme.

I have a simple component called `Vocabulary` which gets a list of `VocabularyEntry`-Objects from a `vocabularyService` and renders it.

```
import React from 'react';
import vocabularyService from '../services/vocabularyService';

export default class Vocabulary extends React.Component {
    render() {

        let rows = vocabularyService.vocabulary.map((v, i) => <tr key={ i } >
            <td>{ v.src }</td>
            <td>{ v.target }</td>
        </tr>);
        // render rows
    }
}
```

The `vocabularyServise` ist very simple:

```
import { VocabularyEntry } from '../model/VocabularyEntry';

class VocabularyService {

    constructor() {
        this.vocabulary = [new VocabularyEntry("a", "b")];
    }
}
export default new VocabularyService();
```

Now I want to mock the `vocabularyService` in a test:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Vocabulary from "../../../src/components/Vocabulary ";
import { VocabularyEntry } from '../../../src/model/VocabularyEntry'

jest.mock('../../../src/services/vocabularyService', () => ({

    vocabulary: [new VocabularyEntry("a", "a1")]

}));

describe("Vocabulary tests", () => {

    test("renders the vocabulary", () => {

        let $component = shallow(<Vocabulary/>);

        // expect something

    });
});
```

Running the test causes an error: Vocabulary.spec.js: babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
Invalid variable access: VocabularyEntry.

As far as I unterstood, I cannot use the VocabularyEntry because it is not declares (as jest moves the mock definition to the top of the file).

Can anyone please explain how I can fix this? I saw solutions which required the references insinde the mock-call but I do not understand how I can do this with a class file.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The problem is that all `jest.mock` will be hoisted to the top of actual code block at compile time, which in this case is the top of the file. At this point `VocabularyEntry` is not imported. You could either put the `mock` in a `beforeAll` block in your test or use `jest.mock` like this:

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Vocabulary from "../../../src/components/Vocabulary ";
import {VocabularyEntry} from '../../../src/model/VocabularyEntry'
import vocabularyService from '../../../src/services/vocabularyService'

jest.mock('../../../src/services/vocabularyService', () => jest.fn())

vocabularyService.mockImplementation(() => ({
  vocabulary: [new VocabularyEntry("a", "a1")]
}))
```

This will first mock the module with a simple spy and after all stuff is imported it sets the real implementation of the mock.

Comment: This seems to be a good approach! I tried this but it causes an error when the `Vocabulary` tries to  to call `vocabularyService.vocabulary.map` because`vocabularyService.vocabulary` is undefined. I logged out the `vocabularyService` and it is a jest-mock-function. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Ah sorry, there was a bug in my code, `mockImplementation` needs to return a function not just the object.

Comment: Not working for me :( please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771844/mock-mockimplementation-not-working.

Comment: When I do this, I get `myService.mockImplementation is not a function`.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Moving `jest.mock` to `beforeAll` gives the same error and using `mockImplementation` gives `TypeError: mockedModule.mockedFunction is not a function`.

Comment: @thisismydesign Any luck in solving this issue?

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427443/2771889

Comment: your `jest.mock(...)` does not work here. There is `import` to a variable. Then it mocks again by `vocabularyService.mockImplementation(...)`. The issue is a stopper to check mock object. If it is intentionally, then it should be named with starting `mock...`. For this questions this response is right - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399966/6344916.

Answer (score 140):

You need to store your mocked component in a variable with a name prefixed by "mock".
This solution is based on the Note at the end of the error message I was getting.

> Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock
> variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable
> names prefixed with `mock` are permitted.

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Vocabulary from "../../../src/components/Vocabulary ";
import {VocabularyEntry} from '../../../src/model/VocabularyEntry'

const mockVocabulary = () => new VocabularyEntry("a", "a1");

jest.mock('../../../src/services/vocabularyService', () => ({
    default: mockVocabulary
}));

describe("Vocabulary tests", () => {

test("renders the vocabulary", () => {

    let $component = shallow(<Vocabulary/>);

    // expect something

});
```

Comment: This produces the error: `Cannot access 'mockVocabulary' before initialization`

Comment: The solution is to use `var` not `const`

Comment: [**don't** use `var`, use `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var)

Answer (score 58):

If you are getting similar error when upgrading to newer Jest [19 to 21 in my case], you can try changing `jest.mock` to `jest.doMock`.

Found this here – https://github.com/facebook/jest/commit/6a8c7fb874790ded06f4790fdb33d8416a7284c8

Answer (score 9):

```js
jest.mock("../../../src/services/vocabularyService", () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  const VocabularyEntry = require("../../../src/model/VocabularyEntry");

  return {
    vocabulary: [new VocabularyEntry("a", "a1")]
  };
});
```

I think it should work with dynamic imports as well instead of `require` but didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

When implementing a `jest.fn()` in a module, which was mocked with `jest.mock`, make sure you do the following two steps:

1. The variable name should begin with `mock`.
2. If you wrote something like `coolFunction: mockCoolFunction`, make sure to change it to `coolFunction: (...args) => mockCoolFunction(...args)`. This way, Jest doesn’t need to know what `mockCoolFunction` is, as long as you haven’t run the function.

For further information, I recommend [this blog post](https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/fix-jest-mock-cannot-access-before-initialization-error).

Comment: Please look at this question facing same issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73977384/the-module-factory-of-jest-mock-is-not-allowed-to-reference-any-out-of-scope

Comment: This is the solution that helped me! I had to change it to (arg1) => mockCoolFunction(arg1) in my case but that will vary depending on your assertions and how your function is called

Answer (score 2):

For a project I worked on, I tried all the solutions listed here and none of them worked.

I was mocking the module like this:

```js
import { myModuleFn } from 'myModule';

jest.mock('myModule', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...jest.requireActual('myModule'),
    myModuleFn: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

Using `Object.assign` instead of spread operator fixed the error:

```js
jest.mock('myModule', () => {
  return Object.assign({}, jest.requireActual('myModule'), {
    __esModule: true,
    myModuleFn: jest.fn(),
  })
});
```

I suspect it has to do with the jest or compiler configuration specific to the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue started after I was upgrade my react-native project to v0.61 using react-native-git-upgrade.

After I have tried everything I could.  I decide to clean the project and all my tests back to work.

```
# react-native-clean-project
```

However watch out when running the react-native-clean-project, it can wipe out all ios and android folder including native code, so just answer N when prompted. In my case I just selected wipe node_modules folder.