# Mock.mockImplementation() not working

Tags: jestjs

I have a service class

Service.js

```
class Service {
}
export default new Service();
```

And I am trying to provide a mock implementation for this. If I use something like this:

```
jest.mock('./Service', () => { ... my mock stuff });
```

It works fine, however I'm not able to access any variables declared outside of the mock, which is a bit limiting as I'd like to reconfigure what the mock returns, etc.

I tried this (inspired by this other StackOverflow article: [Service mocked with Jest causes "The module factory of jest.mock() is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649699/service-mocked-with-jest-causes-the-module-factory-of-jest-mock-is-not-allowe))

```
import service from './Service';

jest.mock('./Service', () => jest.fn);

service.mockImplementation(() => {
    return { ... mock stuff }
);
```

Unfortunately when I am trying to run this, I get the below error:

```
TypeError: _Service2.default.mockImplementation is not a function
```

Comment: It's a React Native project (set up with create-react-native-application, aka expo), Jest is 20.0.4. Node: 7.2.0, Npm:  5.3.0

Answer (score 51):

I had same problem as @Janos, the other answers didn't help either. You could do two things :

1. **If you need to mock only a function from Service, in your test file:**

   ```js
   import service from './Service';

   jest.mock('./Service', () => jest.fn());

   service.yourFunction = jest.fn(() => { /*your mock*/ })
   ```
2. **If you need to mock the entire Module:**

   Say your service.js is in javascript/utils, create a javascript/utils/_*mocks*_ and inside it create a service.js file, you can then mock the entire class in this file, eg:

   ```js
   const myObj = {foo: "bar"}

   const myFunction1 = jest.fn(() => { return Promise.resolve(myObj) })

   const  myFunction2 = ...

   module.exports = {
     myFunction1,
     myFunction2
   }
   ```

   then in your test file you just add:

   ```js
   jest.mock('./javascript/utils/service')
   ```

   ...functions exported from the mockfile will be then hit through your test file execution.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the problem. The most voted does not solve the is not a function issue.

Comment: Solution 1 will replace service by a mock which wont be restored between each test, right ?

Comment: if i could upvote this twice, i would.

Comment: With Typescript, option 1 won’t work but will throw the error: ”Cannot assign to 'yourFunction' because it is a read-only property”

Answer (score 18):

The mock is equal to jest.fn. You need to call jest.fn to create a mocked function.

So this:

```
jest.mock('./Service', () => jest.fn);
```

Should be:

```
jest.mock('./Service', () => jest.fn());
```

Comment: This did not work either. In this case service.mockImplementation didn't even exist.

Comment: This didn't work and the asker explicitly mentioned that it didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

ran into similar issues and resolved it by using `.mockImplementationOnce`

```
jest.mock('./Service', () => jest.fn()
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return { ... mock stuff }
  })
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
   return { ... mock other stuff }
  })
);
```

now when you run another test it will return the second mock object.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! Maybe not that convenient, but it worked out for me!

Answer (score 4):

You need to store your mocked component in a variable with a name prefixed by "mock" and make sure you return an object with a default property as you import your Service from the default in your "main.js" file.

```
// Service.js
class Service {
}
export default new Service();

// main.test.js (main.js contains "import Service from './Service';")

const mockService = () => jest.fn();

jest.mock('./Service', () => {
    return {
        default: mockService
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I was resetting the mock before each test.  If you do that, be sure to reconfigure the mock implementation.

For example, change this:

```
  let value;
  let onPropertyChange: OnPropertyChangeCallback = jest.fn((changes: any) => {
      value = changes["testValue"];
    });

  const user = userEvent.setup();

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
```

to this:

```
  let value;
  let onPropertyChange: OnPropertyChangeCallback;

  const user = userEvent.setup();

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();

    onPropertyChange = jest.fn((changes: any) => {
      value = changes["testValue"];
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and the cause was that ".spec.js" file had an

```
import jest from "jest-mock";
```

After removing this line, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case *mockImplementation* didn't work because I copy paste tests and forgot to remove "async" keyword in this place `it('test description', **async** () => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

My file had no default export but instead various other exports, one of which I needed to mock. This ended up working for me:

```
// services.test.js
const services = require('./services');

...

const innerFunction = jest.fn(() => console.log("calling innerFunction"));
services.functionToMock = jest.fn(() => ({innerFunction}))
```

I was then later able to test my `innerFunction` was properly called by doing

```
...
expect(innerFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove async from your test and DO NOT await expect!

WRONG

```
it.only('throws error on private visibility', async () => {
    await expect(getSteamData(mockSteamId)).rejects.toThrow(ErrorMessage.PRIVATE_VISIBILITY);
  });
```

RIGHT

```
it.only('throws error on private visibility', () => {
     expect(getSteamData(mockSteamId)).rejects.toThrow(ErrorMessage.PRIVATE_VISIBILITY);
  });
```