# Vue router's injection fails during a Jest unit test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-router

In a .vue file with Composition API (and Vue 3), set up the router:

```
const router = useRouter()
```

Mount the .vue file in a jest test:

```
const wrapper = mount(Lookup)
```

On execution, produces:

```
console.warn
    [Vue warn]: injection "Symbol([vue-router]: router)" not found.
      at <Anonymous ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
      at <VTUROOT>
```

Mocking it results in the same output:

```
useRouter().push = jest.fn()
```

Setting [provide](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global) results in same output:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
...
const wrapper = mount(Lookup, {
  global: {
    plugins: [useRouter],
    provide: {
      router: {},
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: `useRouter` is not a plugin, so that should not be in `global.plugins`. Show more context of your `useRouter()` usage in the component.

Comment: @tony19 The `useRouter()` is completely unused in my component for this example. 
It's declaration breaks within the component breaks only when Jest mounts it.

It works as expected in the component if I add back usage of it within the component (which doesn't effect Jest's current outcome).

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem. Can  you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solution allows me to mock `useRouter()` in Jest. Note that `useRouter()` is the only way to use `vue-router` for composition API because `this` is unavailable:

```
const routerPushMock = jest.fn();

jest.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  useRouter: () => ({
    push: routerPushMock,
  }),
}));

test('...', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(vueFile)
  ...
```

Comment: Very important thing to notice for people like me, who fought it for a 3 hours, is that you can't put jest.mock() inside of describe() or test(), it wouldn't work this way. It seems like jest.mock() should be in the root of a spec file.

Comment: It appears that writing "jest.mock" is also very important for some reason. Putting "import mock = jest.mock" then "mock('vue-router', ...)" doesn't work for me. I need to specifically call "jest.mock('vue-router', ...)".

Comment: thanks, @IgorNikiforov, it is very helpful comment. Although I read your comment after spending 2 hours :P

Comment: If you receive a `The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables` error try changing the name of the mock you create, such as `routerPushMock` to something that begins with the word `mock` like `mockRouterPush`. Got that from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649699/service-mocked-with-jest-causes-the-module-factory-of-jest-mock-is-not-allowe

Answer (score 8):

If someone has additionally this error

```
babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
```

I recommend to write it like this

```
const mockPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  useRouter: () => ({
    push: mockPush,
  }),
}));
```

It is important to name it `mockPush` (mockXYZ) because according to: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2567 this specific naming is an escape hatch.